# How to disable Kint in local environment under Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I'm using Kint via Composer in Laravel 4 by loading kint first in composer.json so that dd() is defined by kint, not laravel (suggested [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/308b3721a8e63acde6aa0c0e5f2ba42ecaf4b2be#commitcomment-3187215)).

I want to leave debug calls in my app, and disable Kint if not in the local environment.  I'm successfully using config overrides for Anvard using the following structure:

`/app/config/local/packages/provider/package_name/overridefile.php`

Unfortunately, this is not working for Kint with the following structure:

`/app/config/packages/raveren/kint/local/config.php` or
`/app/config/packages/raveren/kint/local/config.default.php`

The [Kint documentation](http://raveren.github.io/kint/#installation) states:

> You can optionally copy the included config.default.php and rename to config.php to override default values…

…which works for me (`/vendor/raveren/kint/config.php`)

How do I achieve this:

- **without editing a file in the /vendor/ directory that will get overwritten by composer**
- **so that kint is only enabled in the local envirnoment**

---

I've also tried adding the following to a helpers.php file which is called before composer in /bootstrap/autoload.php as suggested [here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10877):

```
<?php
isset( $GLOBALS['_kint_settings'] ) or $GLOBALS['_kint_settings'] = array();
$_kintSettings = &$GLOBALS['_kint_settings'];

/** @var bool if set to false, kint will become silent, same as Kint::enabled(false) or Kint::$enabled = false */
$_kintSettings['enabled'] = false;

unset( $_kintSettings );
```

(but no dice :)

Any suggestions? TIA!

Comment: Author of Kint here, thank you for giving it a try and hope it helps. I am actively researching & planning to rearrange settings location to make life of composer users easier, I just don't have a clear solution yet: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18751125/179104

Comment: hi @Raveren! I think Laravel would look for /Vendor/Raveren/Kint/src/config/config.php as an override.. maybe Kint could check there, too? `php artisan publish:raveren/kint` copies config override files into the correct location...

Comment: I've created an issue here: https://github.com/raveren/kint/issues/94 and I'll look into this situation when time allows it, thank you for contributing! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. I'm not sure if this is the ideal way to do it, but this works, and seems Laravel'ish:

```
// top of app/start/global.php
Kint::enabled(false);
```

and

```
// app/start/local.php
Kint::enabled(true);
```

(assuming you've got a local environment defined: see @TheAlpha's answer for more info)

http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#start-files

Comment: Accidental downvote, and I don't have the reputation to undo it seems. Unless you make an edit. Sorry about this, but if you make a trivial edit, I will happily undo my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `kint` but checked the documentation and found that, to disable `kint` output, you may use (in runtime)

```
// to disable all output
Kint::enabled(false);
```

In `Laravel` you can check the environment using

```
$env = App::environment();
if($env == 'your_predefined_environment') {
    Kint::enabled(false);
}
```

To configure your environment, you may check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration).

**Update :** I've setup my local environment as givel below (in `bootstrap/start.php`)

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('*.dev'),
));
```

And in my local machine, I've setup a virtual mashine which has `laravel4.dev` as it's base url, so if I visit the app using `laravel4.dev or laravel4.dev/logon` then I can check the environment in my `BaseController.php` and it detects the local environment because of `.dev`

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(App::environment() == 'local') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In your case, I don't know where is the first debug/trace you used to print the output, so you should keep the environment checking and disabling the `Kint` code before you use any `debug/trace` but you may try this (if it works for you) but you can check the environment in your `filter/routes` files too.

Comment: tx! can you suggest where I should put that code? I'd love to follow convention if possible.. (also.. whoops, copy pasta error in my Q - I did try `enabled=false`, edited)

Comment: tx for the detailed answer! Tx, `Kint::enabled(false)` works for me if I put it at the top of routes.php or config/app.php... I'll leave the question open for a bit, as I'd love a solution with a conventional config/override.. tx again!