# Changing default environment in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 the default configuration environment is 'production'. This means that if you run an artisan command without the `--env` option, it assumes the production configuration. This can be seen in `\Illuminate\Foundation\Application::detectWebEnvironment()` which is called by `detectConsoleEnvironment()` when no `--env` option is set.

This behavior has become a risk with my development environment. It's really easy to forget the --env option and, say, unintentionally run a migration on your production database. (Yes, that happened but thankfully it was a minor change.) I'm close to just renaming my production environment config to 'real-production' but it seems like there should be a more elegant solution.

**TL;DR**

How can I change the default environment in Laravel 4 such that artisan commands do not run on production by default?

Comment: I think [this answer][1] is what you are looking for...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739750/1272001

Comment: I don't know your setup, but in general dev, staging and production shouldn't be able to access each others environment variables which means what you did would't be possible. Rather, it is safer to have production as default as dev environments potentially leaks confidential information, for example in error messages. Laravel has some documentatation about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks Antonio for prompting me to reconsider domain detection.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
(
    // Empty string is to set development as the default environment for 
    // artisan commands.
    'development' => array('dev.foo.com', ''),
    'test' => array('test.foo.com'),
    'production' => array('www.foo.com', 'foo.com'),
));
```

Adding '' as a development domain effectively sets development as the default environment for artisan commands, presumably because the domain name is blank when the application is invoked from the command line. I tested and it seems anything `== false` will work. I also verified this does not interfere with the detection of the production or testing environments.

Comment: Since the release of Laravel 4.1 domain detection is no longer possible for deciding environment which means this answer no longer works. http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1

Comment: It is possible, you just need to manually do it (opposed to using `detectEnvironment`). It is not recommended though because some of those PHP globals can be spoofed in some cases (depending on your server config). Using `hostname` is a little silly for those of us who run on many servers each with different hostnames (like EC2).

Answer (score 10):

In bootstrap/start.php you can set the environment:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{

    return 'development';

});
```

But you can do many things like:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('your-machine-name'),

));
```

And

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return $_SERVER['MY_LARAVEL_ENV'];
});
```

Comment: I'm aware of this and use the second method to match the domain. This actually gives me a good idea and... yes. Setting 'development' => array('') effectively sets 'development' as the default environment for artisan. I checked and this does not interfere with normal environment detection by domain.

Answer (score 4):

You can try modifying app/start.php file to add second parameter on desired environment as **TRUE** i.e.
 to enable local environment it looks like

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('homestead',true),

));
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the most elegant solution that I've found is from this blog post:
http://stevegrunwell.com/blog/laravel-application-environment/

The advantages:

1. No need to hardcode an array of development machines into a git committed file `start.php`.
2. Fallback to server environmental variables in production.
3. Easy persist local development environment by modifying the `environment.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

      'staging' => array('baichebao_test'),
      'local' => array('*.local', '*'),
 ));
```

like my example, put your default environment in the last item of array, and add "*" to it's manager hostname. and it works in laravel 4.X

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 4.2 you will not be able to do destructive artisan migrations without being prompted:

> Destructive migration operations now require confirmation or --force when being run in production.

[Change log for 4.2 is here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/changes.json)