# Laravel 4.2 says my application is in production. How do I turn this off?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a fresh install of Laravel.  When running `php artisan migrate:refresh` I get a message saying `Application In Production!  Do you really wish to run this command?'`

I know this is an update in 4.2, however I can't figure out how to turn it off.

I found in the source that it comes from `Illuminate\Console\ConfirmableTrait` and runs if this if test passes : `if ($this->getLaravel()->environment() == 'production')`

I'm not sure why it thinks I'm in production.  I never setup any environments.  This is the default environment detection, which I'm still currently using.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('homestead')

));
```

Also, if I set a production environment to a hostname that isn't my machine, I still have the same problem.

Comment: For vagrant users - host name is not your pc but virtual machine, like: vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64. I found it running echo gethostname(); die;

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just specify a machine name for the host that matches a given environment, then `laravel` will automatically detect the environment (default is `production`), for example:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    //'local' => array('homestead'),

    'local' => array('*.dev', gethostname()),
    'production' => array('*.com', '*.net', 'www.somedomain.com')
));
```

[Read the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669462/changing-default-environment-in-laravel-4?rq=1) as well.

Comment: Alright, that fixed it.  Thanks.  I should mention though that I changed 'local' to 'development' (which are the same thing in my case) because I was getting an 'access denied 'homestead'@'localhost'' error, which is strange since my user is root, not homestead.

Comment: @surfer190, `bootstrap/start.php`, read more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration).

Comment: For Lumen enable `Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');` in bootstrap\app.php

Comment: This is a problem I'm facing through Travis CI. I don't have permission nor the ability to change the machine name. What would I do in this scenario?

Answer (score 13):

Setting your environment to something other than production is The Right Way.  [See the accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24092409/2908724)

But, if you're looking for *A Quick Fix* you can use (in UNIXoid environments):

```
yes | php artisan migrate:refresh
```

All this does is send a stream of "y" to the program, which acts like you pressed "y" when prompted.

I find this to be a little better than `--force`, as not all the artisan commands support force.

Comment: @Arcrammer Curious, I wonder why that is. At any rate, give this code a try: `$app->detectEnvironment(); $env = getenv('ENV') ?: 'production';` then use this command line: `ENV=local php artisan migrate:refresh`.  The basic point being that L4.2 requires you call detectEnvironment, but after that you can set `$env` to whatever you like.

Comment: I don't have this problem. I was just passing by! haha Thanks, though.

Comment: Update: Artisan has an `--env` flag which allows you to set your preferred environment. I can confirm once again that piping `yes` cancels the command, although there's also an `-n` flag (which stands for 'no interaction') and using that prevents Artisan from asking for confirmation. Also, I'm using Laravel 5+ for this particular application.

Comment: Another Update: I take it back! I could have sworn that worked but it doesn't work now. However, you can pass `--force` which will run the migrations without asking for confirmation. See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4753#issuecomment-46433295

Answer (score 5):

In case if anyone stumbled upon this question while searching for similar problem in a `lumen` installation I'd suggest to check the `.env` file and add `APP_ENV=local` if its not already there. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help someone else. I suddenly had an issue where my dev site I was building stopped connecting to the DB saying:

```
PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'forge' failed
```

I was also receiving errors such as the OP when trying to run `artisan migrate:refresh` etc, the error was stating that i was in production etc etc.

After much head scratching (!) I found that my hostname value set inside the /bootstrap/start.php was wrong, because my hostname had changed on my macbook pro!? I have no idea how but it changed from something like `RobMacbookPro2.local` to `RobMacbookPro.local`. This meant it fell back to production thus loading the incorrect database.php file with the standard DB=forge (which was wrong)

Check this guide:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration

Pay particular attention to the code:

```
<?php

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('your-machine-name'),

));
```

On a mac and probably linux? you can determine your hostname by typing `# hostname` in terminal.

Hope that saves someone some time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for Laravel 4.2.

but in my case `--force` helped me:

```
php artisan migrate --force
```