# Set an ENV variable for APP_ENV to development

Tags: macos, laravel, environment-variables, development-environment, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to set a global variable for my environment so that `APP_ENV` is globally defined as `development`.

I am using zsh and specifically the oh-my-zsh dotfiles on Mac OS X Mavericks.

I am unsure how to do this. I know it is possible to set the environment in httpd-vhosts.conf, but I am using apache dynamic multiple hosts, so my httpd-vhosts.conf looks like this:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#

#allow access to the Hosts directory where your sites are
<Directory "/Volumes/site/%1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /Volumes/site/%0/public/
ServerAdmin user@example.com
ServerName vhosts.dev
```

Moreover, I also develop some apps using laravel and spawn a virtual server using `php artisan serve` which wouldn't take a APP_ENV directive from the apache httpd-vhosts.conf file.

I would like to set it as part of my overall shell or system-wide on the machine.

Any advice?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24092409/741747).

Comment: That would works per project. What I want is set it globally, so I can use a more dynamic setup for my laravel config/app.php. You can set it such that I can have lines such as `'debug' => (bool) getenv('app.debug'),` and based on my global ENV setting, it will determine that I am in a development environment. This, for a distributed team with 4 debs each with their own local hostname, you can set it so you have one `laravel` environment called `development` and then each machine's own environment variables can be determined dynamically across multiple projects without redoing the config.