# Laravel quickstart migration doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I have been doing the Laravel's quickstart this morning and I am having some issues with the migration part. I am running this on Windows 8.1, using the last version of XAMPP, the last one of Laravel and the CMD of windows for the commands.

I have created the migration file "users" as you can see in the next piece of code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

/**
* Run the migrations.
*
* @return void
*/
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id', true);
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}

}
```

The migration table is created and I am using the next one for creating the users table:

```
php artisan migrate
```

And here is the answer:

```
Aplication in production!

Do you really wish to run this command? yes
Nothing to migrate.
```

(I can't show the pic because it is my first question)

Hope you can help me, I want to keep trying this framework but I don't know how to solve this, have been googling for an hour and nothing worked.

Comment: Are you saying that the name of the migration file is `users`?

Comment: The name of the migration file is migrations

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4.2 says my application is in production. How do I turn this off?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092234/laravel-4-2-says-my-application-is-in-production-how-do-i-turn-this-off)

Comment: This is not the problem I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved it using a MySQL server and avoiding phpMyAdmin, since it is not working for me using the migrations commands.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the migration has been ran already. That's why it says '*Nothing to migrate*'. To verify, check the content of the table `migrations` and you will see there is aready an entry for the users table migration.

To rollback (undo) the last migration and run it again use these command:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
php artisan migrate
```

To rollback (undo) and run again ALL the migrations use these command:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
php artisan migrate
```

The one command equivalent of the last two is:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

BTW, if you want to get rid of the warning **Aplication in production! Do you really wish to run this command?** you must [configure your environment](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than required migrations file in migrations folder it may not work and showing error message "Too many Argument ".

So when finish to create table then delete which has done.