# Environment issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('*localhost*'),
    'test'  => array('chan.app'),
));
```

This is how I set in boostrap/start.php, and I set ip in hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 chan.app
```

No matter I type `http://localhost/` or  `http://chan.app`, `App::environment()` always reveal `production`, therefore I can't change database config for it.

Comment: on the local key, put your real machine name instead of `*localhost*`

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092234/laravel-4-2-says-my-application-is-in-production-how-do-i-turn-this-off

Comment: Hi, I change the code to

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'test'  => array('chan.app'),
 'local' => array(gethostname())
));

and echo environment it shows local, but if I enter by chan.app it shows local too, it should be show test right?

Comment: Isn't it because `chan.app` is also on `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: yes, is that mean I can't simulate production and local environment in my own computer right?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suppose

Comment: Do you use Laravel 4.1 or 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

Because of security issues, the use of **url domains** in environment is forbidden. Laravel says to use **hostnames** instead.

***This is why I doubt, that Laravel would recognise (detect) your configuration correctly, as both are on the same machine.***

From the [4.2 Upgrade Guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade):

> **Environment Detection Updates**
>
> For security reasons, URL domains may no longer be used to detect your
>   application environment. These values are easily spoofable and allow
>   attackers to modify the environment for a request. You should convert
>   your environment detection to use machine host names (hostname command
>   on Mac, Linux, and Windows).

**EDIT**

**Let's say, you want a local and a live environment.**

**1. Create folders for each configuration:**

- Create a folder `local` & `live` inside `/app/config/`
- Inside each of those folders you create the config file(s) you wish to override from `/app/config/`,

For example, in your `live` (production) environment, you don't want to have the `debug` option activated.

- Create a file `app.php` in the `/app/config/live` folder.
- Inside, you'll just return the desired options to override, as defined in the original `/app/config/app.php`.

  `return array('debug' => false);`

In the local environment, 'debug' would be set to true, for development.

**2. Add the environment to the framework:**

In your `/bootstrap/start.php` file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('local-machine-name'),
    'live' => array('yourdoamin.com')
));
```

### That's the important part:

**- Development (local): --> machine name**

**- Production:         --> root-url (yourdomain.com)** which represents the "machine" name

See the [docs about environment config](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Open your CMD (Mac, Linux, and Windows) and type the command:

```
hostname
```

this will return the name of your computer. Then use that name:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('ComputerName'),
));
```