# Laravel doesn't detect my local (development) database config file

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, development-environment

My Laravel application is running on my local computer. When I run my app, Laravel uses my production database configuration and throws an Exception:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'production_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is strange because when I check current environment using `artisan` it says :

```
Current application environment: development
```

and my `development` database config file has a different username and password.

also I have stated in `bootstrap/start.php` that :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'development' => array('*.dev', gethostname()),
    'production' => array('*.com', '*.net', '*.org', '*.ir')
));
```

I don't know why Laravel insist on using `production` configuration although I'm in `development` environment.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879482/environment-issue-in-laravel/26926674#26926674 . Try to search deeper, this question was asked already many times ;-) The development environment should have the machine name

Comment: @pc-shooter, thanks for comment, but I've tried them all. got no luck.

Comment: For me it works with development=machine name, production=domain. What are the folders names?

Comment: @pc-shooter, I just have development folder right now. so on my local machine it should overwrite default configuration

Comment: Try to add the production folder too, as mentioned in the linked answer

Comment: Can you post your folder structure and `database.php` files pls?

Comment: @pc-shooter I've omitted production line and tested agin, but no luck. I'm sure my structure is OK =), cause it was working this morning.

Comment: Did you try `'development' => array('your-machine-name'))`? Are you working on linux or windows? Are the login credentials for your DB ok?

Comment: Is the folder name under `app/config`  `development`?

Comment: are you using laravel 4 oder 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid this issue is to do the following:

**in /bootstrap/start.php**

Replace the default environment detection with:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'local';
});
```

This will check for the presence of an environmental variable which is set by apache/nginx assuming you are running Homestead or similar.